# Matching the scatter points colour with the Image colour bar

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I have made this GUI with PyQt5:

[image]

How can I make the colour of the points in the bottom plot match the colour bar in the 2D plot above? And change accordingly when I change the bar max/min ?

---

MWE:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys
import numpy as np

width = 1000
height = 500

x = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
def func():
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
    return np.exp(-X**2/10 - Y**2/2)

array = func()
sumxaxis = np.sum(array, axis=0)
sumyaxis = np.sum(array, axis=1)

class layout():
    def setup(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.resize(width, height)

        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.window)
        self.horizontallayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.window.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.plot = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(self.window)

        self.horizontallayout.addWidget(self.plot)
        self.view = self.plot.addPlot()
        self.img = pg.ImageItem(border='k')
        self.img.setImage(array, border = 'k')
        self.view.addItem(self.img)
        self.viewbox = self.view.getViewBox()

        self.hist = pg.HistogramLUTItem()
        self.hist.setImageItem(self.img)
        self.hist.setLevels(0, 1)
        self.hist.gradient.loadPreset('viridis')
        self.plot.addItem(self.hist, colspan=1)

        self.plot.nextRow()
        self.plot2 = self.plot.addPlot(colspan=1)
        self.plot2.setMaximumHeight(200)
        self.plot2.plot(-x,sumyaxis,symbol='o',symbolSize=1, symbolBrush=('w'), pen=None, clear=True)


class Window(pg.Qt.QtGui.QMainWindow, layout):

    def __init__(self, shot = None):

        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setup(self)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = pg.Qt.QtGui.QApplication([])
    Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to change the scatter plot to the same colourbar as the 2D image, but I have not yet managed to make it change its colour as I drag the colour bar cursor!

[image]

New MWE:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys
import numpy as np

width = 1000
height = 500

x = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
def func():
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
    return np.exp(-X**2/10 - Y**2/2)

array = func()
sumyaxis = array[:, len(array)//2]

class layout():
    def setup(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.resize(width, height)

        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.window)
        self.horizontallayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.window.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.plot = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(self.window)

        self.horizontallayout.addWidget(self.plot)
        self.view = self.plot.addPlot()
        self.img = pg.ImageItem(border='k')
        self.img.setImage(array, border = 'k')
        self.view.addItem(self.img)
        self.viewbox = self.view.getViewBox()

        self.hist = pg.HistogramLUTItem()
        self.hist.setImageItem(self.img)
        self.hist.setLevels(0, 1)
        self.hist.gradient.loadPreset('viridis')
        self.plot.addItem(self.hist, colspan=1)

        self.colours = self.hist.getLookupTable(img=array)
        self.cmap = pg.ColorMap(pos=np.linspace(self.hist.getLevels()[0], self.hist.getLevels()[1], len(self.colours)), color=self.colours)

        self.plot.nextRow()
        self.plot2 = self.plot.addPlot(colspan=1)
        self.plot2.setMaximumHeight(200)
        self.c = self.cmap.map(sumyaxis, 'qcolor')
        self.plot2.plot(-x,sumyaxis,symbol='o',symbolSize=10, symbolBrush = self.c, pen=None, clear=True)

class Window(pg.Qt.QtGui.QMainWindow, layout):

    def __init__(self, shot = None):

        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setup(self)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = pg.Qt.QtGui.QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the sigLookupTableChanged signal and implement the logic to update the symbolBrush of PlotDataItem:

```
    # ...
    self.plot.nextRow()
    self.plot2 = self.plot.addPlot(colspan=1)
    self.plot2.setMaximumHeight(200)
    self.curve = self.plot2.plot(
        -x,
        sumyaxis,
        symbol="o",
        symbolSize=10,
        pen=None,
        clear=True,
    )
    self.hist.sigLookupTableChanged.connect(self.handle_sigLookupTableChanged)
    self.handle_sigLevelsChanged()

def handle_sigLookupTableChanged(self):
    colours = self.hist.getLookupTable(img=array)
    cmap = pg.ColorMap(
        pos=np.linspace(*self.hist.getLevels(), len(colours)),
        color=colours,
    )
    c = cmap.map(sumyaxis, "qcolor")
    self.curve.opts["symbolBrush"] = c
    self.curve.updateItems()
```

Comment: "AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'handlesigLevelsChanged'
"

Comment: @SuperCiocia Have you literally copied my code? I do not think so

Comment: Yes I have just copied it. Anyway, I manged to get it to work -  i removed the `self.handle_sigLevelsChanged()` and changed the line before to `self.hist.sigLevelsChanged.connect(self.handle_sigLookupTableChanged)`

Comment: @SuperCiocia `handlesigLevelsChanged` is different to `handle_sigLevelsChanged`

Comment: Thanks. For my own understanding, how did you know this was the syntax? I had looked at the source code for [HistogramLUTItem](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/HistogramLUTItem.html) and could not find the function that was updating the 2D image colours with a changing colour bar.

Comment: Must have copied the error wrong, the error I get is `AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'handle_sigLevelsChanged' `

Comment: 1) Although it is not documented (perhaps it is a bug) it is observed that the sigLevelChangeFinished signal is emitted when the sliders are changed 2) mmm, I don't have that problem, Note: that code must be part of the "layout" class

Comment: E.g. if I now want to connect the change of the markers on the right side of the histogram to changing the colour of the bottom plot, *where* should i be looking for the function that could do this?

Comment: Also, do you know why the same trick doesn't work to change the colour of `symbolPen`? I get `AttributeError: 'QColor' object has no attribute 'widthF'`

Comment: Actually I fixed it with `self.curve.opts["symbolPen"] = [pg.mkPen(QColor(i)) for i in c]`

Comment: @SuperCiocia Don't expect one code to apply to another.